# How to add a country code picker to app in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio-dolphin

The implementation is in the *[build.gradle](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/tutorial_using_tasks.html)* file, but I'm still getting "Cannot resolve class com.hbb20.CountryCodePicker" in the main activity

This is the *build.gradle* file:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
}

android {
    namespace 'com.example.assignment1'
    compileSdk 33

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.assignment1"
        minSdk 21
        targetSdk 33
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"


        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
}
dependencies {

implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.5.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.6.1'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
implementation 'com.hbb20:ccp:2.6.1'
}
```

**This is the activity_main.xml:**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">



<ImageView
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_background"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
    android:id="@+id/logo"/>

<com.hbb20.CountryCodePicker
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    app:ccp_areaCodeDetectedCountry="true"
    android:layout_centerInParen="true"
    android:layout_marginleft="100dp"
    android:layout_marginright="100dp"
    android:id="@+id/contrycodePicker"
    app:ccp_autoDetectCountry="true"
    android:layout_above="@id/centerhorizontalline"/>
```

The <com.hbb20.countrycodepicker> shows up as an error. What is the problem?

Comment: The OP has left the building: *"Last seen more than a month ago"*

Answer (score 1):

You must take the following steps when you encounter a problem when adding a new dependency.

**First**

You must ensure that the correct repositories are used
in the repositories list in **build.gradle(project)**

```
allprojects {
 repositories {
     maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
     google()
     mavenCentral()
     mavenLocal()
 }
}
```

**Second**

Go to men *File* → *Sync project*

[image]

These steps work fine for me.